# How can i make my checkbox checked by itself

Tags: java, button, checkbox

I'm basically facing an issue with a checkbox. Indeed, I'd like to use a button which is gonna look for a boolean value in my database, and if the value is true and that i click on the button, the box is going to get checked by itself.

```
if(myValue.isTrue()) 
{
this.mybox."getchecked()";
}
```

But I don't know how to do so, which methods to use, and have not been able to find any results for netbeans do you guys have any solution, thanks for all.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by:  `this.mybox.setSelected(true);`